# Why I am getting "bash: export: `=/usr/jdk/jdk-1.8.0_71': not a valid identifier" message?

Tags: java, bash

I tried to set path and JAVA_HOME variables, and I added the following commands to ~/.bashrc file.

```
export JAVA_HOME =/usr/jdk/jdk-1.8.0_71
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

then to apply all the changes into current running system I run

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

command in terminal,
but I am getting message saying that

> bash: export: `=/usr/jdk/jdk-1.8.0_71': not a valid identifier

How to resolve this?

Comment: Typo. Remove the space. `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/jdk-1.8.0_71`

Comment: Remove the space before the =

Comment: It works,Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace below line

```
export JAVA_HOME =/usr/jdk/jdk-1.8.0_71
```

with

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/jdk-1.8.0_71
```

Try removing space.